# Nested elements with ng-click attributes do not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I have something like the following:

```
<div ng-click="class.divClick()">
  <p>Content</p>
  <div id="target"></div>
</div>

------
divClick = () => {
  doStuff();
  $("#target").append("<a href="#" ng-click="class.aClick()">Link</a>");
}

aClick = () => {
  $("#target").html("");
}
```

Clicking in the div calls class.divClick(), but clicking on the link does not result in class.aClick() being called, it only results in class.divClick() being called.  I don't need the div to be clickable while the anchor is present.  I attempted to use ng-disabled while tracking a disabled property, but that didn't seem to stop the div click from firing and doStuff running when clicking on the link.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You append the content with jQuery - it knows nothing about Angulars scope. You need to use `$compile` to insert dynamic HTML that has scope events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile new html. But this is not a good way. You souldn't manipulate DOM in Angular.

This is the way you should prefer. (I don't know typescript so you may need to use "class." instead of "$scope.")

```
<div ng-click="class.divClick()">
  <p>Content</p>
  <div id="target">
    <a href="#" ng-click="class.aClick()" ng-if="scopeVariableBoolean">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

------
divClick = () => {
  doStuff();
  $scope.scopeVariableBoolean = true;
}

aClick = () => {
  $scope.scopeVariableBoolean = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't pick up the `ng-click="class.aClick()"` if it was injected via jQuery.

But the top-level ng-click does pick up events that bubble up via the DOM's event propagation model. One more caveat: `ng-if` creates a new scope, so setting a variable as a child of the parent scope as in Kursad's answer is not recommended. Instead, you should put the flag that controls the visibility of the link in an object (such as the `class` object you're using)

```
<div ng-click="class.divClick()">
  <p>Content</p>
  <div id="target" ng-if="class.visible">
    <a href="#" ng-click="class.aClick(); $event.stopPropagation()">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

------
divClick = () => {
  doStuff();
  $scope.class.visible = true;
}

aClick = () => {
  $scope.class.visible = false;
}
```